# Fastest way to generate a matrix using beta.rvs in python

Tags: python, numpy, performance, random, scipy

I want to generate of matrix of size (500, 1000000) using beta.rvs function of scipy.stats.

I have tried multithreading but still it is taking too much time. Is there any other ways to reduce the execution time? Is there some other library which can do the same thing?

Comment: Whilst it isn't implemented yet, you could take a look at how the other distributions are implemented in [numba-stats](https://github.com/HDembinski/numba-stats) and try and do something similar for the beta distribution.

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you show the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org) to compute the values in [parallel with prange](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import beta
import numba as nb

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a, b = 0.5, 10

N = 50, 1000000

result1 = beta.rvs(a, b, size=N)

@nb.njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def beta_rvs(a, b, shape):
    out = np.empty(shape, dtype=np.float64).reshape(-1)
    size = np.asarray(shape).prod()
    for i in nb.prange(size):
        out[i] = np.random.beta(a, b)
    return out.reshape(shape)

result2 = beta_rvs(a, b, N)

%timeit -n 1 -r 1 beta.rvs(a, b, size=N)
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 beta_rvs(a, b, N)
```

Output:

```
3.62 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
696 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Output with the requested shape:

```
39.1 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
6.75 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Histograms:

```
plt.hist(result1.ravel())
plt.hist(result2.ravel())
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @Nin17 answer, you may want to improve speed further by using simple repeat distribution trick. **Use only if you do not care that distribution will not be "perfect", when you are ok with "good enough".**

For very large array shapes, usually you do not care that values repeat themselves. As long as distribution looks the same. Here I repeat values and multiply them by constants close to 1 so the values still vary a bit.

```
def beta_rvs_fast_est(a, b, shape, subsample_factor=10):
    flattened_size = np.prod(shape)
    true_beta = beta_rvs(a, b, int(np.ceil(flattened_size / subsample_factor)))
    sub_samples = []
    multipliers = np.linspace(0.98, 1.02, subsample_factor)
    for multiplier in multipliers:
        sub_samples.append(true_beta * multiplier)
    return np.concatenate(sub_samples)[:flattened_size].reshape(shape)
result3 = beta_rvs_fast_est(a, b, N)
```

This may give you 3-5x speed-up depending on `subsample_factor` and your array size.

You may want to play with constants (0.98, 1.02) as I've chosen them very arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.default_rng().beta(a, b, size=(500, 1000000) )`